# I have been posting on this forum using a name without registrating. How can I register now?

Tags: user-accounts

Hi, 
I have been posting on this forum using a name without registrating. How can I register now?
The forum recognised my IP and I could accumulate points. But since yesterday I am not anymore logged, and it seams that I have lost my account. Is there a way to recover it?

Fred

Comment: @Fred This question belongs to the meta or ask the mods directly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you log in using a gmail, hotmail or openid account?
2. What was your other user name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1567/fred ; if so, go to https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery and provide your Hotmail e-mail address. If it should not work, we will mere you with your new account https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1709/fred .